# Trying to view website just on my personal computer while developing

Tags: web

I thought this would be simple enough but apparently not... Currently I'm just trying to make some simple HTML/JS files to test out bootstrap, and I'm leaving them on my C drive, and attempting to view them from within my browser (chrome). However, when I try, it just tells me the HTML file I'm pointing at isn't a website and that's the end of it.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It just says this

No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/.../test.html

Comment: If you have python, try `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to serve content in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your browser in admin mode. Open the properties window of your browser executable (*C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe*), go to Compatibility tab and check "Run this application as administrator"